# Why is Views not rendering any Content

Tags: views, javascript, nodes

Why would Views not be showing its contents, for example...

Here's what I have in the source code, this is a straight view source from the browser.

```
<div class="view view-full-bg-homepage-slider view-id-full_bg_homepage_slider view-display-id-page view-dom-id-a6084598ca3a2b981c6f6344dfe47c51">
```

*Whole bunch of whitespace here*

```
</div>
```

I'm using Latest versions of everything. Views UI and Context UI are each turned off at the moment, as a test, but this hasn't seemed to help.

Could it be a memory error? Can provide more info, just not to sure what to provide at this stage.

Comment: Could you have overriden template files? Try switching theme to see if the content appears. Do you get any output when you preview your view?

Comment: Check few things: * Are you getting the preview correctly in  the view configuration screen? *What kind of view are you rendering (block,page,content pane...)? *What format are you using check under the format tab? *Are you using filters? *Are you able to see the content in its own url? *Are you using custom templates?

Comment: Pontus, Nope no output when I preview in the admin either. Switched Theme to Bartik and no change. I'm using a Zen 5.5 Sub-theme at the moment

Comment: José, Views block, Views Slideshow (settings seem to be in order), filters seem to be OK too. Can't be seen on its own URL. 

The odd thing is that this is all happening on the Production Server. On staging the same things are present, but no content inside the view. Theme has come over via SVN, and appears to be mirrored correctly with staging.

Comment: Try clearing the cache and look for errors in the logs, both watchdog and PHP

Comment: some things to check: 1) is there content in the preview, 2) do other views work or is a module wide problem, 3) are any filters of any sort that would restrict content, 4) try entering a NO RESULTS BEHAVIOUR under advanced - does it show?

Comment: Thanks Geoff and all, your prompt to look deeper at filters helped me. My view was looking at non published nodes, which is correct, but my node on the production site was published. Hence no view.